# Best way to set up a testing database for an automated TFS build process

Tags: database, unit-testing, nhibernate, tfs, build-automation

I am using a customized workflow that runs a couple of test projects. Some of these projects use a database (I know this should be in a separated context, but I cannot change the tests code) to run some test cases.

I don't know if it's relevant or not, but I'm using XUnit as Testing Framework and nhibernate as ORM.

What I did is create a custom activity that sets up all the necessary databases in a SQLEXPRESS server for the test projects and attach them temporarily and also the activity modifies the .config files pointing to the temp databases I created. So far so good.

The problem here is that I don't want to have .mdf templates that unfortunately are out-of-date (due to logical db changes) and have to be updated manually.

The other problem I'm facing is that not only do the templates spoil the automation of this process, but the developers that access these projects out of the build definitions are not able to easily launch the tests locally on their machines. They have to get the MDF, mount the DB, configure the test project, and run. That's too many operations to give developers the will to unit test their code.

What is the best approach or does anybody have any advice on where I should start looking into possible solutions at this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Use database projects and deploy them to your test databases.

Comment: How often is the database schema changing in this project?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Let's say once a week approximately: Sometimes developers need to add new fields in the entities which requires new columns, and that sort of modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the only way to test databases well locally is to either mock them or use an embedded database with some simple data in it.

Really both of those approaches will take work from your development team.

I would strongly recommend mocking the database since it doesn't require making backups and restoring a database before running tests.  If you mock the database with code the tests will run practically instantly and you won't have any external dependencies to manage.

You want your developers to either find an existing interface with nhibernate that they can mock (Moq is a good library to do mocking -  http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or introduce interfaces at the data access level so they can fake the database calls.

The embedded approach would be a pretty bad fit here I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am going with the embedded approach since we don't have enough time to make modifications in the test projects, but what you suggested makes perfect sense.